# How to calculate mode of a grouped data when the formula is not defined?

Tags: statistics

When calculate the mode of a grouped data, i use the formula: $M_0=u_m+\dfrac{n_m-n_{m-1}}{(n_m-n_{m-1})+(n_m-n_{m+1})}.(u_{m+1}-u_m)$ with $[u_m;u_{m+1})$ is the group with highest frequency $n_m$.

But i cannot use it for this example:

| Group | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| $[45;49)$ | 6 |
| $[49;53)$ | 7 |
| $[53;57)$ | 7 |
| $[57;61)$ | 7 |
| $[61;65)$ | 3 |

I can use the formula to find mode of the group $[49;53)$ and $[57;61)$ but cannot use with $[53;57)$ cause the denominator equal to zero.

If i use the relationship Mode = 3Median - 2Mean, i only get 1 mode. If the is 3 group with highest frequency, i thought it should have 3 modes.

So with this grouped data, or the data with more round have the same frequency, what can i used to calculate their mode? Thank you for answer.